# On a web shopping cart written in PHP, should I check IP address everytime?

Tags: php, security

Are too many people on rotating IP for this to be a good security measure (among others of course) or is this a standard practice?

Also can anybody enlighten me on some concepts I should pay particular attention to in securing a shopping cart?

So far I have form validation, rotating session keys, no sensitive information is stored as a cookie or by javascript, SSL encryption, and all SQL is escaped.

Comment: what are checking the IP address for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote [0xA3:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/618301/binding-of-ip-address-with-session-id)

> I don't think that this is a good
>   idea. Subsequent request from the same
>   users might not necessarily come from
>   the same IP address because the
>   request might come from a different
>   proxy. IIRC this used to be the case
>   for all AOL users and might be the
>   case for other providers or some
>   corporate networks, too.
>
> It is better to secure your session
>   with page tokens to prevent
>   highjacking a session.

Answer (score 2):

It'd eliminate any chance of mobile users using your site - they're generally all behind NAT gateways and would appear to come from only a few IPs for each provider.